# В UserCreationForm не переводится до конца текст (хотя стоит ru-RU). Как можно изменить форму?

Tags: python, django

[image: Наглядно]

```
<div class="form-section">
    <h2>Регистрация на сайте</h2>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Смотри свой `django.po` файл https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.po

Comment: ты нашёл решение? У меня такая же проблема...

Answer (score 0):

Вот это вам должно помочь
[документация тэга переводчика](https://djbook.ru/rel1.7/topics/i18n/translation.html#trans-template-tag)

> Шаблонный тег {% trans %} может переводить как обычную строку, заключенную в одинарные или двойные кавычки, так и содержимое переменой:

```
<title>{% trans "This is the title." %}</title>
<title>{% trans myvar %}</title>
```

> тег blocktrans позволяет отмечать сложные предложения, состоящие из строк и переменных, обеспечивая перевод с помощью подстановок

```
{% blocktrans %}This string will have {{ value }} inside.{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]